# How to load data in R with the 'caret' library?

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I'm trying to evaluate several cross-validation predictive models in R with the 'caret' library, but an error message appears everytime I try to load the dataset. I know I'm doing something wrong, but can't see the mistake (I **summarized** the code below):

```
> ticData<-read.table("tic-tac-toe.data.txt",header=F, sep=',')
> ticData
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9      V10
1    x  x  x  x  o  o  x  o  o positive
2    x  x  x  x  o  o  o  x  o positive
3    x  x  x  x  o  o  o  o  x positive
4    x  x  x  x  o  o  o  b  b positive
5    x  x  x  x  o  o  b  o  b positive
6    x  x  x  x  o  o  b  b  o positive
[…]
> colnames(ticData) <- c("topl","topm","topr","midl","midm","midr","botl","botm","botr","class")
> head(ticData)
  topl topm topr midl midm midr botl botm botr    class
1    x    x    x    x    o    o    x    o    o positive
2    x    x    x    x    o    o    o    x    o positive
3    x    x    x    x    o    o    o    o    x positive
4    x    x    x    x    o    o    o    b    b positive
5    x    x    x    x    o    o    b    o    b positive
6    x    x    x    x    o    o    b    b    o positive
> complete.cases("tic-tac-toe.data")
[1] TRUE
> library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
> set.seed(100)
> trainIndex <- createDataPartition(ticData$class, p=0.7, list=FALSE, times=1)
> head(trainIndex)
     Resample1
[1,]         1
[2,]         2
[3,]         4
[4,]         6
[5,]         7
[6,]         9
> Train <- ticData[ trainIndex,]
> Test <- ticData[-trainIndex,]
> install.packages("klaR")
> install.packages("C50")
> install.packages("nnet")
> install.packages("kernlab")
> library(caret)
> ticData$class=as.factor(ticData$class)
> head(ticData)
  topl topm topr midl midm midr botl botm botr    class
1    x    x    x    x    o    o    x    o    o positive
2    x    x    x    x    o    o    o    x    o positive
3    x    x    x    x    o    o    o    o    x positive
4    x    x    x    x    o    o    o    b    b positive
5    x    x    x    x    o    o    b    o    b positive
6    x    x    x    x    o    o    b    b    o positive
> fitControl<-trainControl(
+ method="nb",
+ number=10)
> set.seed(100)
> nbFit<-train(class~.,data=ticData,
+ method="nb",
+ trControl=fitControl,
+ verbose=FALSE)
Error: Not a recognized resampling method.
```

I'm still learning, many thanks in advance :)

Comment: the `data()` function in a base function with R that already has predefined datasets, when you run `data(ticData)`, it can't find the dataset, because it's not in that function, just type `ticData` should output your dataset.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see that the last line of code is not needed for my purpose here. I'm now strugling for training the cross-validation methods, but maybe I should post another qustion. I get an error message saying "Not a recognized resampling method" when trying to train the "nb" (Naïve Bayes) method.

Comment: Where are you getting that error? the only thing I see in your code is t`rainIndex <- createDataPartition(ticData$class, p=0.7, list=FALSE, times=1)`. update your code with your nb training attempt so we can see where you get stuck, it might be a simple argument error

Comment: Many thanks, I updated the code with my last progress.

Comment: it doesn't look like the function `train()` can use the explicit method 'nb', if you type `?train()` you get the help page for the function, you might be getting different packages and their respective functions mixed up

Comment: True, I had to write "cv" (cross-validation) instead. I see the problem now.